# Update Attributes of a Specific Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Let's say I have a bunch of cards listed on my wall show action. When you interact with a card (click it for example), I want to update that card's attributes.

I'm currently doing this by getting the card's attributes with Javascript, adding them to a card form and submitting the form remotely.

I have the card's ID, but how do I tell the form which card I want to update?

What should the form and controller update action look like?

This is what I have so far

Form

```
<%= form_for(@card, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :list_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :order %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def update
    @card = Card.find(params[:id])

    if @card.update_attributes(shared_params)
        redirect_to edit_card_path(@card, format: :html)
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

Comment: You may have a hidden field within the form and populate that field via javascript with the card id being clicked, then submit the form.

Comment: But if I just put the ID in a form field, how does Rails now which card to update?

Comment: What  understand from the code above `@card = Card.find(params[:id])`, *params[:id]* would be id of another card irrespective of what you clicked, as you are not passing it. My suggestion is to pass it like `hidden_field_tag :card_id`, populate this field with card id(may be from an onclick event) and submit the form via JS. **The form_for @card may hold a different ID, but you have to use the ID passed from hidden field**

Comment: Cheers lad! fewfwefff

Comment: My form is submitting to the create action I think. How do I turn the form into and update form?

Comment: `form_for(@card, remote: true, method: :patch)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same new template for edit too. The only requirement here is the object you wanted to edit.

So, first get you edit action ready in controller as

```
def edit
  @card = Card.find(params[:id])
end
```

### edit/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@card, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :list_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :order %>
<% end %>
```

In the cards show page, add a link to the edit action as

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_card_path(card.id) %>
```

Comment: But I'm not using the edit action. Everything is located on the wall/show action. And I don't know which record is being saved until the user interacts with it.

Comment: So, I think you are trying to do that using AJAX way. Hope [https://codediode.io/lessons/1904-ajaxified-one-page-application-with-rails#7-ajaxify-the-edit-action] helps you .